# react newforms, throw error on server response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, newforms

I am using [react newforms](http://newforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for react form handling. I find it really good but couldn't figure out how to trigger an error on a given input field if the server responses with an error.

For example you got a login form and you decide not to show an alert box under the form but throw a custom error that newforms catches and displays an error message `Username does not exist` right below the input field. (like it does on clientside validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`form.addError()`](http://newforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms_api.html#Form#addError) for this:

```
form.addError('username', 'Username does not exist.')
```

If there isn't another state change happening associated with the server response, you may need to force your component to re-render.

---

It also supports async validation, so it's possible to do the server call inside a custom validation method and get the form to add the error for you (suitability depends on when the server call needs to happen).

http://newforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html#asynchronous-validation

Comment: Great!  I also did `form.data.username = ''` to reset the input field (if that is the correct way). How do I `form.fields.username.focus()`? What about alphanumeric validation? P.S: I know about the async feature and using it :)